# Recursive CTE for a family tree keeps going into an infinite loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, family-tree, recursive-cte

I am trying to design a RDBM model for a family tree using SQL Server and currently I have the 3 tables that looks somewhat as follows

**Members -** Stores basic details of members of the family.

```
---------------------
| ID    | Firstname |
---------------------
  1000  Ranjith
  1001  Shilpa
  1002  Ramamkrishna
  1003  Jayasree
  1004  Sabarinadhan
  1005  Sushama
  1006  Shyamala
  1007  Mukundarao
  1008  Ramadevi
  1009  Gopinath
  1010  Reshmi
  1011  Raj
  1012  Pratham
```

**Families -** Stores the Members.ID of the patners that were together

```
------------------------------
| ID    | Spouse1 | Spouse2 |
------------------------------
  1     1002        1003
  2     1000        1001
  3     1004        1005
  4     1006        1007
  5     1008        1009
  6     1010        1011
```

**Families_Children -** Stores the Families.ID of each family and the Member.ID of the children of that family.

```
------------------------------
| ID    | FamilyID | ChildId |
------------------------------
    1       1         1000
    2       3         1001
    3       4         1002
    4       4         1008
    5       5         1010
    6       6         1012
```

What I want now is to use a recursive CTE to travese the tree given a member ID. So if I give a member ID as 1007, I want to find all families they are part of and then their children's families till the last node in the that particular tree.
This is the query I have so far

```
WITH family_tree AS (
    SELECT 
        f.Id as FamilyId, 
        f.Spouse1Id as Spouse1Id,
        mfs1.FirstName as Spouse1,
        f.Spouse2Id as Spouse2Id,
        mfs2.FirstName as Spouse2,
        fc.ChildId as ChildId,
        mc.FirstName as Child
    FROM Families f
    INNER JOIN Families_Children fc
        ON fc.FamilyId = f.Id
    INNER JOIN Members mfs1
        ON mfs1.Id = f.Spouse1Id
    INNER JOIN Members mfs2
        ON mfs2.Id = f.Spouse2Id
    INNER JOIN Members mc
        ON mc.Id = fc.ChildId
    WHERE f.Spouse1Id = 1007 OR f.Spouse2Id = 1007
    
    UNION ALL
        
        SELECT
            ft.FamilyId, 
            ft.Spouse1Id,
            ft.Spouse1,
            ft.Spouse2Id,
            ft.Spouse2,
            ft.ChildId,
            ft.Child
        FROM 
            Families f, family_tree ft
        WHERE ft.ChildId = f.Spouse1Id OR ft.ChildId = f.Spouse2Id
)

SELECT * from family_tree;
```

The first part of the CTE (family_tree) is pretty straight forward and returns the family where the member with ID 1007 is part of.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
|FamilyId| Spouse1Id| Spouse1| Spouse2Id| Spouse2 | ChildId| Child
------------------------------------------------------------------
  4       1006      Shyamala  1007    Mukundarao  1002    Ramamkrishna
  4       1006      Shyamala  1007    Mukundarao  1008    Ramadevi
```

In the union, I am trying to recurse through the Families table again for each row returned by the family_tree where the child in the family is either spouse1 or spouse2. But the entire thing just keeps going into an infinite loop and I can't figure out what's wrong with the termination clause. Any help would really be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Please update your post with some sample data - enough to reproduce the infinite loop.

Comment: And set a recursion limit on your CTE, then inspect the results, you'll soon see what is going wrong.

Comment: Added some sample data to the tables.

Comment: Added a limit to the CTE call like @DaleK mentioned and it looks like the loop keeps going on the second child and keep repeating the same row.

Comment: So that means your where clause isn't excluding existing matches... but sorry I haven't time to try and work it out

Comment: I think this might be an issue with what you're returning from the recursive part of the CTE. It looks odd to me that you're returning columns CTE (in your case, `family_tree`) and not the table from which you'd get the next level of data (in your case, `Families`). So recursion is returning the same data over and over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took [siggemannen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75690834/9311874)'s advice and updated the DB model to have a single Member_Parents table

```
CREATE TABLE Member_Parents(
    Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    MemberId INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Members(Id),
    ParentId INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Members(Id),
);
```

and was able to solve the problem pretty quickly as follows

```
WITH Family_Tree AS (
    SELECT 
        mp.MemberId,
        mp.ParentId
    FROM
        Member_Parents mp
    WHERE mp.ParentID = 1008

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        mp.MemberId,
        mp.ParentId
    FROM
        Member_Parents mp,
        Family_Tree ft
    WHERE mp.ParentID = ft.MemberId
)

SELECT 
    ft.MemberId,
    mm.FirstName AS Member,
    ft.ParentId,
    mp.FirstName AS Parent
FROM Family_Tree ft
INNER JOIN Members mm
    ON mm.Id = ft.MemberId
INNER JOIN Members mp
    ON mp.Id = ft.ParentId
```

The query turned out to be pretty straight forward without too many joins. I also agree that my CTE was incorrect and I guess it was due to my understanding of the recursive CTE (learnt it just a couple of days back).

It would really be appreciated if you could review this query.

I am now trying to figure out a way to fetch the ancestors for a given member (traverse up the tree).

Thanks.

**UPDATE**
Was able to quickly get the ancestor tree as well for a give member

```
WITH Ancestor_Tree AS (
    SELECT 
        mp.MemberId,
        mp.ParentId
    FROM
        Member_Parents mp
    WHERE mp.MemberId = 1012

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        mp.MemberId,
        mp.ParentId
    FROM
        Member_Parents mp,
        Ancestor_Tree ft
    WHERE mp.MemberId = ft.ParentId
)

SELECT 
    ft.MemberId,
    mm.FirstName AS Member,
    ft.ParentId,
    mp.FirstName AS Parent
FROM Ancestor_Tree ft
INNER JOIN Members mm
    ON mm.Id = ft.MemberId
INNER JOIN Members mp
    ON mp.Id = ft.ParentId
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your db model is flawed (and kinda heteronormative). It's not bad, but not great either.
It would be easier if you had following structure:

Persons : ID,  First,  LastName

PersonParents: PersonID, PersonParentID

So, most people would have two rows in PersonParents table. This way it's easy to iterate the trees up and down.

But if we stick to your model, your CTE looks wrong too, i think it tries to fetch same rows over and over.
If you only wants children using your structure i think this works:

```sql
;with members as (
select *
from (
    VALUES  (1000,'Ranjith')
    ,   (1001,'Shilpa')
    ,   (1002,'Ramamkrishna')
    ,   (1003,'Jayasree')
    ,   (1004,'Sabarinadhan')
    ,   (1005,'Sushama')
    ,   (1006,'Shyamala')
    ,   (1007,'Mukundarao')
    ,   (1008,'Ramadevi')
    ,   (1009,'Gopinath')
    ,   (1010,'Reshmi')
    ,   (1011,'Raj')
    ,   (1012,'Pratham')
) members (id, firstname)
)
, Families as (
select *
from  (
    VALUES  (1,1002,1003)
    ,   (2,1000,1001)
    ,   (3,1004,1005)
    ,   (4,1006,1007)
    ,   (5,1008,1009)
    ,   (6,1010,1011)
) family(id, spouse1id, spouse2id)
)
, Families_Children as (
    select *
    from (
    VALUES  (1,1,1000)
    ,   (2,3,1001)
    ,   (3,4,1002)
    ,   (4,4,1008)
    ,   (5,5,1010)
    ,   (6,6,1012)
) t (id, familyid, childid)
)
, family_tree AS (
    SELECT 
        f.Id as FamilyId, 
        f.Spouse1Id as Spouse1Id,
        mfs1.FirstName as Spouse1,
        f.Spouse2Id as Spouse2Id,
        mfs2.FirstName as Spouse2,
        fc.ChildId as ChildId,
        mc.FirstName as Child
    FROM Families f
    INNER JOIN Families_Children fc
        ON fc.FamilyId = f.Id
    INNER JOIN Members mfs1
        ON mfs1.Id = f.Spouse1Id
    INNER JOIN Members mfs2
        ON mfs2.Id = f.Spouse2Id
    INNER JOIN Members mc
        ON mc.Id = fc.ChildId
    
    UNION ALL
        
        SELECT
            f.ID, 
            f.Spouse1Id,
            m.FirstName,
            f.Spouse2Id,
            m2.FirstName,
            fc.ChildId,
            m3.FirstName
        FROM  family_tree c
        INNER JOIN Families f
        ON  f.spouse1ID = c.ChildID
        OR  f.Spouse2ID = c.ChildID
    INNER JOIN Families_Children fc
        ON  fc.familyID = f.ID
    INNER JOIN Members m
        ON  m.ID = f.spouse1ID
    INNER JOIN Members m2
        ON  m2.ID = f.spouse2ID
    INNER JOIN Members m3
        ON  m3.ID = fc.ChildID
)
select *
from family_tree
```

As you see, it's kinda awkward, cause you have to do this double join and OR thing to get both parents. Also, this model doesn't allow adoptions, unmarried kids or unknown parents.

Finally, I don't think you can combine both up and down actions in one recursive CTE, so you need two to cover the both parents and children.

Comment: I wanted to cover all the cases you mentioned (didn't think of unknown parents). I kept the 2 columns in Families table generic (no gender limitation) and nullable to accomodate single parents, unmarried kids and adoptions. But I get what you mentioned about the CTE being awkward. Let me try using your suggested DB design and see what I can come up with.